# Custom Source data in handleDragEnd [ React-beautiful-dnd ]

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I wanna Add **Drag&Drop** feature to a Grid View where items are grouped

Every things looks fine with **react-beautiful-dnd** but I didn't find a way to customise the data of source and target in order to get them in `onDragEnd` function

```
onDragEnd = result => {
   const { source, destination } = result;
   ....
 }
```

I get always just `index`, `draggableId` , `droppableId`

There no way to pass in more data to drag source ?